# How to get count of INNER join and count of count of all items?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, paid_users and paid_users_no more. Essentially, a paid user can have many accounts.

Their schemas look like this:

```
paid_users:
payor_id | user_email | payor_email | payment_start_date
---------------------------------------------------------
         |            |             |


paid_users_no_more:
user_id | payment_stop_date
---------------------------
        |
```

I wrote a query to grab which accounts used to pay and which ones no longer do in a given month (churned accounts):

```
SELECT payor_id, count(*) as "churned accounts" FROM paid_users_no_more 
INNER JOIN paid_users 
ON paid_users_no_more.user_id=paid_users.user_id 
WHERE paid_users.payment_start_date NOT BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2015-08-30 23:59:59'::timestamp 
AND paid_users_no_more.payment_stop_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2015-08-30 23:59:59'::timestamp 
GROUP BY paid_users.payor_id;
```

This gives me the number of churned accounts for each payor_id in August - how would I also grab the total number of accounts the payor had? Ie, the below query gives me the number of accounts for each payor_id:

```
SELECT paid_users.payor_email,count(*) AS "total accounts" 
FROM paid_users 
WHERE paid_users.payment_start_date NOT BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2015-08-30 23:59:59'::timestamp 
GROUP BY paid_users.payor_email;
```

I want be able to somehow join the two resulting tables to see both "churned accounts" and "total accounts" (as I want to calculate churned revenue and the more accounts somehow has, the cheaper their cost is) - is there a way to join these tables?

Thank you!

Comment: Haven't read the question, just the title, but the answer (I bet) is `GROUP BY <whatever> WITH ROLLUP;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your two queries Union Compatible, then you can combine the results and aggregate with an additional query:

```
    SELECT payer, 
           sum(churned_accounts) AS "churned_count",
           sum(total_accounts) AS "total_count" 
    FROM (
      SELECT CAST(payor_id AS CHAR(50)) AS "payer", 
             count(*) as "churned accounts", 
             0 AS "total accounts" 
      FROM paid_users_no_more 
      INNER JOIN paid_users 
        ON paid_users_no_more.user_id=paid_users.user_id 
      WHERE paid_users.payment_start_date NOT BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2015-08-30 23:59:59'::timestamp 
      AND paid_users_no_more.payment_stop_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2015-08-30 23:59:59'::timestamp 
      GROUP BY paid_users.payor_id

      UNION

      SELECT CAST(paid_users.payor_email AS CHAR(50)) AS "payer", 
             0 AS "churned accounts", 
             count(*) AS "total accounts" 
      FROM paid_users 
      WHERE paid_users.payment_start_date NOT BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND '2015-08-30 23:59:59'::timestamp 
      GROUP BY paid_users.payor_email
    ) as All_Accounts
```

Having the `0 AS "total_accounts"` and `0 AS "churned_accounts"` means the two queries have the same fields present, which make the `UNION` possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - when I run this query, I get "ERROR:  UNION types integer and character varying cannot be matched
LINE 17:       SELECT paid_users.payor_email AS "payer", 
ERROR: UNION types integer and character varying cannot be matched"

Comment: I tried doing payor_id instead of payor_email for the second email butthen I get "ERROR:  column "churned_accounts" does not exist
LINE 2:            sum(churned_accounts) AS "churned_count","

Comment: Sorry - didn't realise payor_id and payor_email were different data types.  I have updated the SQL to cast them both to a `CHAR` data type so that they can be combined in a `UNION` query.

Comment: Hey bunnmatt - I get an error of "ERROR:  column "all_accounts.payer" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1:     SELECT payer, "

Comment: Well actually I previously got "ERROR:  column "churned_accounts" does not exist
LINE 2:            sum(churned_accounts) AS "churned_count"," but I assumed it was because "churned accounts" and "total accounts" had spaces instead of "_"